# Displaying parent case name in a child case export in CommCare

Tags: commcare

Is there an easy way to display the name of a parent case in the child case data export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an "easy" way to do this so it just comes through in the export.  Your options would be:

1. Save the name of the parent case to the child case so it is a child case property. This isn't a great idea since if the name of the parent changes later it will be incorrect on the child case. You'd need to be very confident the case names won't change to use this method.
2. Export the parent_case_id in your export, then also export the parent cases separately. Use a vlookup to match them in Excel after the fact.